# JCR-SQL2 InvalidQueryException using UNION - expected: <end>

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr-sql2

I am trying to use UNION to collect all the unique identifiers(jcr:uuid) of multiple node types and getting an InvalidQueryException, while the actual SELECT statements by themselves are successful.

jackrabbit version: 2.12.1

```
SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType1]
UNION
SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType2]
```

StackTrace:

```
SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType1]
UNION(*)SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType2]; expected: <end>
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerObject.getRepositoryException(ServerObject.java:113)
  at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerQueryManager.createQuery(ServerQueryManager.java:74)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2078.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerQueryManager_Stub.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.ClientQueryManager.createQuery(ClientQueryManager.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains more than one selector, therefore you have to use a selector name in your query. The name is only optional if there is exactly one selector.

Try this:

```
SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType1] AS a
UNION
SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType2] AS a
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver but the above Suggested solution didn't work either.<br> I have tried the below queries and they don't work either. <br><br>                            `SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType1] AS a
UNION
SELECT [jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType2] AS a`<br><br>                                 `SELECT a.[jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType1] AS a
UNION
SELECT a.[jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType2] AS a`<br><br>                                           `SELECT a.[jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType1] AS a
UNION
SELECT b.[jcr:uuid] FROM [base:nodeType2] AS b`<br><br>